# Is there a easy way to estimate how quickly something will dissolve depending on its surface area?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, kinetics, solvents

How exactly does the surface area of a solid for example a cube of sugar, affect the speed of its solvation. I guess everyone has observed that a batch of fine grounded sugar or salt dissolves much faster than a large chunk.

Is there a simple way to estimate this effect ? Are there kinematic models that include surface area as parameter ?

Comment: This provides a nice summary of the historical development of models for the rate of dissolution: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-018-25821-x. Since the dissolution of a solid into a liquid happens at the interface between the 2 phases, the surface area of solid in contact w/ the liquid has been considered a key component of dissolution models for over a century: "[In the year 1900] Brunner and Tolloczko determined that the rate of mass removal is proportional to the surface area of the dissolving particle, adding an important new parameter to this diffusion-based model of dissolution".

Comment: @theorist Thank you, that article is quite informative. So the proportionality of the dissolution rate (mass removal rate) is linear in regard to surface area, according to the Nernst-Brunner equation.